# Oracle PLSQL return one row type

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Hi i want create a function that return **multiple values** in only **one row**:

```
create or replace TYPE foo_type AS OBJECT (
col1 NUMBER             ,
col2 VARCHAR2(150 BYTE) 
);

CREATE FUNCTION foo_function( ) RETURN foo_type 
as
 row_type foo_type;

select
 b1,  -- NUMBER TYPE            
 b2   -- VARCHAR2(150 BYTE) TYPE
into 
 row_type 
from 
 table_xxx 
where 
 rownum=1; --Only one row!

return row_type;

END  foo_function;
```

If i compile i received: **ORA-00947 not enough values**

I've tried:

```
select
 b1,  -- NUMBER TYPE            
 b2   -- VARCHAR2(150 BYTE) TYPE
into 
 row_type.col1,
 row_type.col2 
from 
 table_xxx 
where 
 rownum=1; --Only one row!
```

And the function is compiled but when id run:

```
select foo_function() from dual;
```

Oracle return: **ORA-06530 reference to uninitialized composite**

Answer (score 1):

you defined it as object at database level, so this object has to be initialized.

You could either do this to initialize it with `null` values before doing your select as the following:

```
row_type := foo_type(null,null)
```

But the more fitting solution here would be changing the select to the following:

```
select
 foo_type(b1,b2)  -- Create a foo_type from the select
into 
 row_type -- throw this initialized foo_type into your variable row_type
from 
 table_xxx 
where 
 rownum=1; --Only one row!
```

Comment: Answer is ok but I can't agree with you about `you defined it as object at database level, so this object has to be initialized.` Even a subprogram  level defined type variable must be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

```
select b1, b2
into   row_type 
from   table_xxx 
where  rownum=1;
```

Is throwing `ORA-00947 not enough values` because there are two values `b1` and `b2` but only one variable `row_type` to insert them into.

You can either do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo_function( ) RETURN foo_type 
as
  row_type foo_type;
BEGIN                        -- missing BEGIN
  select foo_type ( b1, b2 ) -- You need to put the values into a foo_type object
  into   row_type 
  from   table_xxx 
  where  rownum=1;

  return row_type;
END  foo_function;
```

Or:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo_function( ) RETURN foo_type 
as
  row_type foo_type := foo_type( NULL, NULL ); -- Initialise the object.
BEGIN
  select b1,            b2
  into   row_type.col1, row_type.col2
  from   table_xxx 
  where  rownum=1;

  return row_type;
END  foo_function;
```

Comment: Thanks now when i do: 
select foo_function() from dual; i revied: [foo_type ]
how can i show ALL value insert in returned record?

Comment: @MicheleM `SELECT foo.col1, foo.col2 FROM ( SELECT foo_function() AS foo FROM DUAL )`

Comment: And for do: SELECT col3, col4 ,(SELECT foo.col1, foo.col2 FROM ( SELECT foo_function() AS foo FROM DUAL )) from tab_yyy -- tab_yyy has column col3 and col4